# ExtJs wind direction chart

Tags: extjs, charts, markup

I want to create a wind direction chart, here is an example : http://www.windguru.com
But can't find how to draw arrows on a chart in ExtJs 4.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to have an image for each direction of the arrow (say 12 different images)

In the grid, simply display an image in the cell

Use a template something like this:

```
<img src="/images/arrows/{direction}.gif">
```

and replace {direction} with a value from the store such as "NW" for north-west

Comment: Yes but i need to get those images into a chart .. in other words how can i set the html code into the chart's data? I want a chart because I have many altitudes for each hour  

Here is an example of exactly what I need : http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-symbols